# To serve SSL, does the web server need outbound internet access?

Tags: iis, ssl

I am having a problem with intermediate certificates, and wonder:

Could the problem be (that clients report an intermediate cert is missing), be the result of my web server having zero outbound inet access?

From my knowledge, the server only serves to the client, and the client takes the cert (public key) and then may troll the internet to validate that cert.

This is iis on win 2012, fwiw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS provides a certificate chain to the client using the certificates loaded in the server computer's registry. You need to obtain the missing intermediate certificate and install it onto the server so that it can provide a complete certificate chain to clients.

Comment: IOW, the web server does not need outbound internet access (to reach CAs or such)?

Comment: @samsmith - For *serving* TLS/SSL, no. It's not going to go out and grab CRLs, certificates, etc. (Acting as a TLS/SSL client is a different story.)